# Modify \footcite{} structure

Tags: citing, footnotes, footcite

I am using `\footcite{}` in a research project proposal. This proposal has a page limit. To maximaze the amount of space that I am given, I would like to modify the structure of the citations generated. Currently, `\footcite{}` outputs one column of citations. Is there any way to change this? For example, could I split this one column in half and have two smaller columns of footnote references? Or, even better...could I just have one line of references, like this: 1 Smith 1999, 2 John 2005, 3 Bob 1998... such that each reference immediately follows the prior on the same line?

Any help or point in the right direction is greatly appreciated.